# Post cancellation task in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have a scenario where once we manually cancel a pipeline in Azure DevOps, we need to terminate a particular process (exe). We wanted to know how can a task be triggered in YAML post cancellation, to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @AshwinHariharan, How are things going? Is the suggestion in my answer helpful to you? please have a try with it. Any update, feel free to tell us.

Comment: @Bright Ran-MSFT. Your suggestion worked perfectly for our task. Thanks for the inputs on this.

Comment: Hi @AshwinHariharan, you're welcome, and glad that I can help you solve the problem. If  possible, could you please mark my answer as the solution of this topic? This may be also very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the following ways:

1. If there are multiple jobs in your pipeline, make sure the job that runs the task to `terminate the particular process (exe)` is processed after all other jobs have completed processing (**`Succeeded`**, **`Failed`** or **`Canceled`**). You can use the '**dependsOn**' key to set the execution order of the jobs. For more details, see "[**Dependencies**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#dependencies)".

   Then, as **`@ShaykiAbramczyk`** mentioned, on the job that `terminates the particular process (exe)`, you can use the '**`condition`**' key to specify the condition under which the job runs. For more details, see "[**Conditions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#conditions)".

   ```yaml
   jobs:
   . . .
   - job: string
     dependsOn: string
     condition: eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Canceled')
   ```
2. If there is only one job in your pipeline, make sure the task to `terminate the particular process (exe)` is the last step in the job. You need to put this task to the bottom of the steps list of this job.

   Then also need to specify the condition on the task to `terminate the particular process (exe)`.

   - If using the '**`condition`**' key on this step, this step will be always listed and display in the job run, regardless of whether it is skipped or not.

     ```yaml
     steps:
     - step: string
        condition: eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Canceled')
     ```
   - If using the '`if`' statement on the step, this step will be listed and display in the job run only when the '`if`' condition is met and to run this step. If the condition is not met and the step is skipped, this step will be hidden in the job run.

     ```yaml
     steps:
     - ${{ if eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Canceled') }}:
        - step: string
     ```

Comment: we will try this out

Comment: Hi @AshwinHariharan, any update, feel free to tell us.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the step that terminate the process, and configure him to run only if the pipeline is canceled - with [custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

```
condition: eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Canceled')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the step that terminate the process, and configure him to run only if the pipeline is canceled - with canceled() condition:

```
condition: canceled()
```